# Can't use variadic-function as Action's parameter C#

Tags: c#, delegates, variadic-functions

Need to find a way to pass a delegate **Action** with a **variable number of parameters** (see `MyLog` below) to another method (see `ExtractToDirectory` below `MyLog`).

I have a Log method:

```
public static void MyLog(string variable, params object[] args)
{
  textBoxLog.AppendText(string.Format(message, args) + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

And a call further in the same WinForm class:

```
private void buttonInstall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  using (Stream zipStream = <Get stream from Resources>)
  using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream))
    zip.ExtractToDirectory(@"Z:\", MyLog);
}
```

A static class with a method:

```
public static class ZipFileExtensions
{
  public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive source, string destinationDirectoryName, Action<string, params object[]> myLog)
  {
    myLog("Starting {0} extraction", source.Name);
  }
}
```

The problem is with the declaration of `ExtractToDirectory`.
The `params` keyword gets underlined with error : **Type expected**.

I tried not to put params, but then VS expects an object array instead of variable length parameters as I need.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following [quetzalcoatl answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51661977/1311370), I ended up with this:

---

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
  public delegate void LogAction(string message, params object[] args);
  public void Logger(string message, params object[] args)
  {
    if (args != null)
      textBoxLog.AppendText(string.Format(message, args) + Environment.NewLine);
    else
      textBoxLog.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);
    Application.DoEvents();
  }

  private void buttonInstall_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Logger("Button clicked");
    using (Stream zipStream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Namespace + ".Resources.test.zip"))
    using (ZipArchive zip = new ZipArchive(zipStream))
      zip.ExtractToDirectory(Program.DestinationInstallation, Logger);
}
```

---

```
public static class ZipFileExtensions
{
  public static void ExtractToDirectory(this ZipArchive source, string destinationDirectoryName, MainForm.LogAction myLogger)
  {
    int number = 20180803;
    myLogger("{0} >> {1} (ok)", DateTime.Now, number);
  }
}
```

---

Help was much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Remove 'params' keyword and make it `Action<string, object[]>` and it will probably compile. `params` is only just a syntactic sugar. The function itself is not 'variadic'. It simply takes second parameter of type object[].

Of course, `Action<string, object[]>` will behave as not 'variadic' for all purposes, it will expect you to provide `new []{..}` all the time. Action/Func delegates does not support `params`. You could make your own specialized delegate though:

```
using System;

public delegate void LogAction(string template, params object[] args);

public static void Log(string a, params object[] args)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(a,args);
}

public static void Main()
{
    var act = new Action<string,object[]>(Test.Log);
    act("fooo {0} {3}", new object[]{1, 3, 4, 5});

    var myAct = new LogAction(Test.Log);
    myAct("fooo {0} {3}", 1, 3, 4, 5);
}
```

Comment: It's awesome! I did not figure out how to achieve what I wanted at first, but I finally came out with the exact way to do so following your advices.

Comment: I think you should probably mark this as the answer instead, since he explained the solution in a clear and concise way, whereas the current marked answer just bloats it.